# Use CSS selector and display none on the source

Tags: css, logging, selector

There are seven `divs` that should be printed on screen according to my CSS attributes. I'm working with `:nth-child` selector in order to recognize the specific order of my `divs`.

I decided making the eight onward set as `display:none` - so it means to not be printed on screen. That was easy and it is perfectly working, however, I noticed that when the console log is opened it is different from what is printed on screen. Even though the eight onward placed on is set with `display:none`, the `divs` code are still readable by the browser. To sum up, the `divs` are not printed as I want, but the log loads it on. I'm afraid on it making my navigation slow, due to loading of the content.

Is that possible to make the eight onward to not be readable by the browser?

Here is my code HTML/CSS:

HTML

```
<div class="random-banners">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.random-banners > div:nth-child(1),
.random-banners > div:nth-child(2),
.random-banners > div:nth-child(3),
.random-banners > div:nth-child(4),
.random-banners > div:nth-child(5),
.random-banners > div:nth-child(6),
.random-banners > div:nth-child(7) {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:#006633;
    float:left;
}

.random-banners > div:nth-child(n+8) {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: You want to pass content to the browser that the browser can't see? This should be solved server-side, by not sending that content at all.

Comment: You could set the images as background-images instead of placing them inline, that way the images would not be loaded if `display:none;` was applied. But as @DavidThomas suggests, if you don't want the browser to see the images at all, they should just not be there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`display: none`, doesn't delete the html nodes, it just hides them from the flow of the page, so it is like they are not there but they still exist, so they can be shown, queried and manipulated by javascript or css at any time (yes css as well).

You really should not worry about this as is a normal behaviour. But you should be concerned about your css writing. This way of writing it is better, faster and shorter and does the same:

```
.random-banners > div:not(:nth-child(n+8)) {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:#006633;
    float:left;
}
.random-banners > div:nth-child(n+8) {
    display:none;
}
```